# AssertionError at /create-user/ Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

AssertionError at /create-user/
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

models.py:

```
`class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points_earned = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    downloaded_apps = models.ForeignKey(App, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class Task(models.Model):
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    screenshot = models.ImageField(upload_to='screenshots/', blank=True, null=True)


class App(models.Model):
    app_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='icons/', blank=True, null=True)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)`
```

Serializers:

```
`class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'`
```

views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_user(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.data

            serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.DATA)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response({'message': f"user {data['username']} created"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    except Exception as e:
        return Response({'message': f'{e}'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

json data for post request:
{"username": "user1",
"password": "dummyPass@01"}
after I provide this data, it returns me the above mentioned error

Why does it happen? I checked other similar questions where I found that `return` was missing for most of the cases before `Response()`.

Comment: What does your create_user function return if the request method isn't 'POST' or the serializer is not valid?

Comment: (The answer is nothing, which is where the error is coming from)

Comment: You could add else's to each if statement that raise Exceptions to break out of the try and display an error

Comment: oh yeah, that solved the problem. Thank you